# Remove multi selected rows from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to remove multi rows from table, and I have used the following code but does not work.
I'm use `DataTables v1.10.9`.

```
$('#del_Btn').on('click', function () {
    // 'table' is the instance of table object
    table.row('.selected').remove().draw(false);
}
```

**Full code:**

```
$('#del_MembersBtn').on('click', function () {

if (confirm('Do you want to remove the selected items ?') === true) {
    var selRows = RemoveFromGroupTable.rows({selected: true}).data().pluck(0); // return an object contains selected rows
    var selRowsLength = selRows.length;
    var rows = new Array();
    for (i = 0; i < selRowsLength; i++) {
        rows.push(selRows[i]);
    }

    // remove the selected rows from table
    RemoveFromGroupTable.rows('.selected').remove().draw(false);
    var inputData = {};
    inputData.selectdRows = rows;
    inputData.submit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    $.post(myProp.base_url + 'directory/class/method', inputData, function (outputData) {
        if (outputData.submit == outputData.submit) {
            tips();
        }
    }, 'json');
}
```

}
});

What can I do to remove multi selected rows ?

Answer (score 1):

> **SOLUTION**

Use [`rows`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/rows%28%29) to select multiple rows from the table as shown below

```
$('#del_Btn').on('click', function () {
    table.rows('.selected').remove().draw(false);
}
```

If the button is located inside the table, it would be necessary to use delegated event handler as follows:

```
$('#example').on('click', '#del_btn', function () {
    table.rows('.selected').remove().draw(false);
}
```

where `example` is your table ID.

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9v0wofbh/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it does not work, it just only removes the color from the selected items.  I have updated my question, see my full code.

Comment: @LionKing, added [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9v0wofbh/) to show that my solution works.